# pandas: groupby incident type over yearly tallies

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to create like a pivot table using `groupby` to group by `incidents` over yearly tallies, like so:

Original data (sample):

```
INCIDENT INCIDENT_YEAR
run      2020
walk     2021
jump     2019
run      2021
run      2020
```

And I want to `groupby` to look like:

```
INCIDENT 2019 2020 2021
jump     1
run           2    1
walk               1
```

I know this can be done in Excel, but I want to learn how to do it in pandas.

My best attempt is

```
df.groupby('INCIDENT').count()
```

But that's not giving me the desired columns.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pd.crosstab`:

```
stats = pd.crosstab(df['INCIDENT'], df['INCIDENT_YEAR'])
```

Output:

```
>>> stats
INCIDENT_YEAR  2019  2020  2021
INCIDENT                       
jump              1     0     0
run               0     2     1
walk              0     0     1
```

Comment: `crosstab` is clearly the right answer.

Comment: @richardec is there a way to add a 'totals' column at the very end of the crosstab?

Comment: @Yves easily. A sum of each row or each column?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `crosstab`:

```
out = pd.crosstab(df['INCIDENT'], df['INCIDENT_YEAR']).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=[None])
```

Output:

```
  INCIDENT  2019  2020  2021
0     jump     1     0     0
1      run     0     2     1
2     walk     0     0     1
```

Comment: This is what i wanted, thank you so much!! if i may followup: could i add a second index/dimension? let's say i have a third column: ['DISTRICT']. and i would like to groupby DISTRICT then INCIDENT which then gives me the yearly tallies. how would that look like for crosstab? or would i have to move to `groupby()` for that

Comment: @Yves can you add a sample of input and expected data for such a case to your question?

Comment: @Yves, In this case, `pivot_table` is clearly a best choice :)

Comment: @richardec yes, and i think i figured it out(?) supposing the same third column exists.... i used `df.groupby(['INCIDENT', 'DISTRICT', INCIDENT_YEAR'])[['INCIDENT']].count()`. both your answer and what i just figured is actually what i wanted. im guessing `pd.crosstab` is for simpler crosses/pivots. however im curious if `pivot_table` is the simpler choice. hope that made sense

Comment: @Yves could you include a sample and an expected output of your actual problem?

Comment: if you should so insist, of course!

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2**

If you have another level of grouping:

```
df.groupby(['INCIDENT', 'DISTRICT', 'INCIDENT_YEAR']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

# OR

df.assign(dummy=1).pivot_table('dummy', ['INCIDENT', 'DISTRICT'], 'INCIDENT_YEAR',
                               aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)

# Output
INCIDENT_YEAR        2019  2020  2021
INCIDENT DISTRICT                    
jump     District A     1     0     0
run      District A     0     2     1
walk     District A     0     0     1
```

**Update**

It's possible to use `groupby` too:

```
>>> df.groupby(['INCIDENT', 'INCIDENT_YEAR']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
INCIDENT_YEAR  2019  2020  2021
INCIDENT                       
jump              1     0     0
run               0     2     1
walk              0     0     1
```

You can use `pivot_table` as alternative of `pd.crosstab`:

```
>>> df.assign(dummy=1).pivot_table('dummy', 'INCIDENT', 'INCIDENT_YEAR',
                                   aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
INCIDENT_YEAR  2019  2020  2021
INCIDENT                       
jump              1     0     0
run               0     2     1
walk              0     0     1
```

Comment: I also thought of using `assign` at first, but changed my mind in favor of `reset_index()`. Any preference over either?

Comment: `reset_index` seems a bit cooler to me, although as both produce the same output it matters little :)

Comment: **The Zen of Python**: *Explicit is better than implicit.* `reset_index` is a bit of magic. Why count an index? In fact, I should use `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: @CeliusStingher. I prefer `assign` instead of `reset_index` for the reason I mentioned above about implicit and explicit.

Comment: @Yves. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little bit of variety, although enke's and richardec's answers remain the favorite:

```
df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='INCIDENT',columns='INCIDENT_YEAR',values='index',aggfunc='count',fill_value=0)
```

Outputs:

```
INCIDENT_YEAR  2019  2020  2021
INCIDENT                       
jump            1.0     0     0
run               0   2.0   1.0
walk              0     0   1.0
```